# How to detect overflow of "unsigned" long multiplication in Java?

Tags: java, long-integer, multiplication, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

Java does not have "unsigned" long values, of course, but sometimes signed long values are effectively treated as unsigned long values (the result of `System.nanoTime()`, for example). In this sense, arithmetic overflow doesn't so much mean overflow of a value as much as it means overflow of the 64-bit representation. Examples:

```
Long.MAX_VALUE * 2L  // overflows the signed product but not the unsigned product
Long.MAX_VALUE * 4L  // overflows the signed product and the unsigned product
-1L * 2L             // overflows the unsigned product but not the signed product
```

Testing whether a multiplication overflows seems to be somewhat complicated, since the sign-iness of the operations gets in the way. It may be helpful to note that any negative value multiplied by any value other than 0 or 1 will overflow the unsigned product, since the highest bit of the negative value is set.

What would be the best way to determine whether the product of two "unsigned" long values—which are really signed long values—would overflow the 64-bit representation? Using instances of `BigInteger` is an obvious solution, and I've derived a convoluted test involving only primitive operations, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I don't think `System.nanoTime()` is required to always return positive values.

Comment: Exactly my point. It returns values relative to some unspecified origin, which means negative values are as legitimate as positive values. Effectively, the value returned by System.nanoTime() could be considered unsigned (or sign irrelevant).

Comment: Oh, I see. That adds another dimension to the question, I was only considering the positive half of the values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
As promised in one of my comments to original post I will now post strict and correct solution. It has less divisions that Nathan's own formula (for those interested see last code line in his answer), but it has additional branching, so I am not sure it will be better performance-wise. 
And, alas, it is not one-liner. Here it is:

```
    static boolean unsignedMultiplyOverflows(final long a, final long b) {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // now proceed with non-zero input
        // we branch based upon parity of a and b
        final long aHalf = a >>> 1;
        final long bHalf = b >>> 1;
        final byte aLastBit = (byte) (a & 1);
        final byte bLastBit = (byte) (b & 1);
        if (aLastBit == 0) { // a = 2 * aHalf, meaning unsigned representation of a
            return Long.MAX_VALUE / b < aHalf;
        } else if (bLastBit == 0) { // b = 2 * bHalf
            return Long.MAX_VALUE / a < bHalf; // symmetrical to previous case
        } else { // a = 2 * aHalf + 1; b = 2 * bHalf + 1
            return (Long.MAX_VALUE - bHalf) / b < aHalf;
        }
    }
```

The formal proof is based on investigation of 2 cases, 1. At least one of multipliers is even, and 2. `a`,`b` both odd. I could add it if anyone is interested.
I have unit-tested it on full range of chars : 0 ~ 0xffff for overflow of 16-bit numbers, and also on some random `long` input, comparing results with both Nathan's method and `BigInteger` solution as a reference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Checking for negative is not a sufficient test.

Comment: Well, the question was only about overflowing `unsigned` representation. And I agree with the statement in the question that "note that any negative value multiplied by any value other than 0 or 1 will overflow the unsigned product"

Comment: My point is that an overflow of a multiplication of a pair of positive (signed or unsigned) numbers does not *necessarily* have the top bit set.  In other words, your test gives both false positives and false negatives.  Doesn't it?

Comment: @StephenC No, it doesn't. It somewhat checks if *unsigned* 0xfffffffffffffff divided by `a` is less than `b`, which means 64 bits is not enough to hold `a` * `b`. However, as I edited, there is imprecision in some results, I will try to update with better solution when I get to office.

Comment: Had thought something then walked it back. Need to consider this a bit more, though a large possibility for false positives would still be problematic.

Comment: I see now the solution here is part of the one that I had derived. The result is effectively `b > ((Long.MAX_VALUE / a) * 2L) + 0`, which is the first part of my solution. The difference is that the rhs of my solution replaces the `0` with the obscure term `(((Long.MAX_VALUE % a) * 2L) + 1L) / a`, which is always either 0 or 1 and eliminates the incorrect results. So, I think your solution would have a small possibility for incorrect results.

Comment: @NathanRyan Could you please post your final formula / solution, for a,b > 1 ? I think I have something precise, but it might be bulkier than what you already have.

Comment: @kiruwka The result I derived for signed positive values greater than 1 is `return (a > ((Long.MAX_VALUE / b) * 2L) + ((((Long.MAX_VALUE % b) * 2L) + 1L) / b))`. Note that `a` and `b` can be swapped in the computation.

Comment: @NathanRyan Well, I derived somewhat similar in performance, but with more code and branching on cases when `a` , `b` are even/odd . It should be precise(as your approach seem to be), but definitely verbose. Seems like java's restriction of `unsigned division` makes it very difficult to beat what you already have using primitives. I think it could be useful if you could post your own solution (you could embed it in my answer if you like), may be someone will find it helpful one day. I will try to give it more thinking this week. And +1 for the question, this is interesting.

Comment: @kiruwka My solution is a bit too long to embed in your answer as a comment. I'll post it as a separate answer. Feel free to cannibalize in order to tweak your own solution. If you do so, I'll accept yours (unless something better than the both of ours comes along, of course).

Comment: @NathanRyan Thanks, i will devote some time to it. BTW, thinking about performance of your code, I came up with a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071182 . Ppl don't seem to like it much so far, but may be you could contribute ? Thanks again.

Comment: @NathanRyan I have posted what I derived last week, mentioned in earlier comments. No luck finding better approach. The solution is a bit similar to yours : it boils down to division of `0x7f...f`(i.e. Long.MAX_VALUE) by something derived from the operands and comparing to produce result equivalent to  `unsigned division` of 0xff...f(Max unsigned value) by one of operands needed to perform overflow check.   Do you have any performance numbers of your "formula" vs `BigInteger` approach ? Otherwise, I don't see a practical reason of doing it the way we did - probably hard to read and maintain.

Comment: @kiruwka Accepted, though I think both our answers are sufficiently complicated that the right thing to do is implement using BigInteger, performance be damned. I haven't done anything akin to a timing test, though I suspect the BigInteger approach would be slower. Still, my general philosophy is to implement the easy way, and to profile and re-implement if performance becomes a problem.

Comment: @NathanRyan Absolutely agree, my experience tells me exactly same. Spending hours right now debugging race condition in a highly "optimized" i.e. obfuscated code, pulling my hairs out. Anyways, it was fun and I will try to keep this question in mind and may be use during occasional interviews.

Answer (score 2):

Given two signed long values that we are pretending to be unsigned long values, here is how to determine whether the unsigned product would overflow, using only signed primitive operations (please forgive the pedantry):

```
boolean unsignedMultiplyOverflows(final long a, final long b) {
    if ((a == 0L) || (b == 0L)) {
        // Unsigned overflow of a * b will not occur, since the result would be 0.
        return false;
    }
    if ((a == 1L) || (b == 1L)) {
        // Unsigned overflow of a * b will not occur, since the result would be a or b.
        return false;
    }
    if ((a < 0L) || (b < 0L)) {
        // Unsigned overflow of a * b will occur, since the highest bit of one argument is set, and a bit higher than the lowest bit of the other argument is set.
        return true;
    }
    /*
     * 1 < a <= Long.MAX_VALUE
     * 1 < b <= Long.MAX_VALUE
     *
     * Let n == Long.SIZE (> 2), the number of bits of the primitive representation.
     * Unsigned overflow of a * b will occur if and only if a * b >= 2^n.
     * Each side of the comparison must be re-written such that signed overflow will not occur:
     *
     *     [a.01]  a * b >= 2^n
     *     [a.02]  a * b > 2^n - 1
     *     [a.03]  a * b > ((2^(n-1) - 1) * 2) + 1
     *
     * Let M == Long.MAX_VALUE == 2^(n-1) - 1, and substitute:
     *
     *     [a.04]  a * b > (M * 2) + 1
     *
     * Assume the following identity for non-negative integer X and positive integer Y:
     *
     *     [b.01]  X == ((X / Y) * Y) + (X % Y)
     *
     * Let X == M and Y == b, and substitute:
     *
     *     [b.02]  M == ((M / b) * b) + (M % b)
     *
     * Substitute for M:
     *
     *     [a.04]  a * b > (M * 2) + 1
     *     [a.05]  a * b > ((((M / b) * b) + (M % b)) * 2) + 1
     *     [a.06]  a * b > ((M / b) * b * 2) + ((M % b) * 2) + 1
     *
     * Assume the following identity for non-negative integer X and positive integer Y:
     *
     *     [c.01]  X == ((X / Y) * Y) + (X % Y)
     *
     * Let X == ((M % b) * 2) + 1 and Y == b, and substitute:
     *
     *     [c.02]  ((M % b) * 2) + 1 == (((((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b) * b) + ((((M % b) * 2) + 1) % b)
     *
     * Substitute for ((M % b) * 2) + 1:
     *
     *     [a.06]  a * b > ((M / b) * b * 2) + ((M % b) * 2) + 1
     *     [a.07]  a * b > ((M / b) * b * 2) + (((((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b) * b) + ((((M % b) * 2) + 1) % b)
     *
     * Divide each side by b (// represents real division):
     *
     *     [a.08]  (a * b) // b > (((M / b) * b * 2) + (((((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b) * b) + ((((M % b) * 2) + 1) % b)) // b
     *     [a.09]  (a * b) // b > (((M / b) * b * 2) // b) + ((((((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b) * b) // b) + (((((M % b) * 2) + 1) % b) // b)
     *
     * Reduce each b-divided term that otherwise has a known factor of b:
     *
     *     [a.10]  a > ((M / b) * 2) + ((((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b) + (((((M % b) * 2) + 1) % b) // b)
     *
     * Let c == ((M % b) * 2) + 1), and substitute:
     *
     *     [a.11]  a > ((M / b) * 2) + (c / b) + ((c % b) // b)
     *
     * Assume the following tautology for integers X, Y and real Z such that 0 <= Z < 1:
     *
     *     [d.01]  X > Y + Z <==> X > Y
     *
     * Assume the following tautology for non-negative integer X and positive integer Y:
     *
     *     [e.01]  0 <= (X % Y) // Y < 1
     *
     * Let X == c and Y == b, and substitute:
     *
     *     [e.02]  0 <= (c % b) // b < 1
     *
     * Let X == a, Y == ((M / b) * 2) + (c / b), and Z == ((c % b) // b), and substitute:
     *
     *     [d.01]  X > Y + Z <==> X > Y
     *     [d.02]  a > ((M / b) * 2) + (c / b) + ((c % b) // b) <==> a > ((M / b) * 2) + (c / b)
     *
     * Drop the last term of the right-hand side:
     *
     *     [a.11]  a > ((M / b) * 2) + (c / b) + ((c % b) // b)
     *     [a.12]  a > ((M / b) * 2) + (c / b)
     *
     * Substitute for c:
     *
     *     [a.13]  a > ((M / b) * 2) + ((((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b)
     *
     * The first term of the right-hand side is clearly non-negative.
     * Determine the upper bound for the first term of the right-hand side (note that the least possible value of b == 2 produces the greatest possible value of (M / b) * 2):
     *
     *     [f.01]  (M / b) * 2 <= (M / 2) * 2
     *
     * Assume the following tautology for odd integer X:
     *
     *     [g.01]  (X / 2) * 2 == X - 1
     *
     * Let X == M and substitute:
     *
     *     [g.02]  (M / 2) * 2 == M - 1
     *
     * Substitute for (M / 2) * 2:
     *
     *     [f.01]  (M / b) * 2 <= (M / 2) * 2
     *     [f.02]  (M / b) * 2 <= M - 1
     *
     * The second term of the right-hand side is clearly non-negative.
     * Determine the upper bound for the second term of the right-hand side (note that the <= relation is preserved across positive integer division):
     *
     *     [h.01]  M % b < b
     *     [h.02]  M % b <= b - 1
     *     [h.03]  (M % b) * 2 <= (b - 1) * 2
     *     [h.04]  ((M % b) * 2) + 1 <= (b * 2) - 1
     *     [h.05]  (((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b <= ((b * 2) - 1) / b
     *     [h.06]  (((M % b) * 2) + 1) / b <= 1
     *
     * Since the upper bound of the first term is M - 1, and the upper bound of the second term is 1, the upper bound of the right-hand side is M.
     * Each side of the comparison has been re-written such that signed overflow will not occur.
     */
    final boolean unsignedMultiplyOverflows = (a > ((Long.MAX_VALUE / b) * 2L) + ((((Long.MAX_VALUE % b) * 2L) + 1L) / b));
    return unsignedMultiplyOverflows;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If one starts by determining which value is larger, there will be certain values of the larger and smaller number which guarantee that overflow can or cannot occur.  Assume X is larger; Y is smaller.

If X is below 2^31, or if Y is less than 2, overflow is impossible; otherwise, if X is more than 2^62 or Y is not smaller than 2^32, overflow is certain.  Return if either condition applies.

Otherwise, because of X's lower bound, V=(X>>31)<<31 is known to be between X and X/2.  Because of X's upper bound, V>>31 is less than 2^31 Y is less than 2^32, T=(V>>31)*Y (also equal (X>>31)*Y) can be computed without overflow.  Because V is a multiple of 2^31, T also equals (V*Y)>>31, so we know that T is between (X*Y)>>31 and (X*Y)>>32.

If T is less than 2^31, then X*Y must be less than 2^63 and overflow is impossible.  If T is not less than 2^32, X*Y must be at least 2^63 and overflow is certain.

If neither condition applies, the product will be in the range 2^62 to 2^64.  Overflow may be determined by doing the multiplication directly and checking the sign of the result.  Unlike C, in which signed integer overflow yields Undefined Behavior, Java guarantees that if x and y are positive and x*y is less than 2^64, an arithmetic overflow will yield a negative result.

In summary, code should start by ranking X and Y, and then doing four comparisons and conditional returns.  If none of them yields a dispositive result, it may compute (X>>31)*Y and doing two more comparisons.  If those doesn't yield a dispositive result, one more multiply and test will yield a final answer using, in the worst case, eight comparisons, a shift, and two multiplies (if the rank of X and Y is not known, add another comparison to rank them).

Note that if the original numbers may be negative, some more checking is required to handle some extra cases.  Still, the above approach should be faster than approaches requiring one or more divisions.

Comment: Nice. I'd have to double check the boundaries, but it seems that it works. Also good are the short-circuit returns for wide swaths of input, which avoids much of the calculation altogether. (A more generic result could use the number of leading zeros for `X` and `Y`, rather than the intermediate calculations of `V` and `T`, but computing the number of leading zeros alone is probably more cycles than your solution.) Don't worry about the negative cases; as mentioned in the question, those are trivial.

Comment: @NathanRyan: With a processor and framework where one could counting leading zeroes faster than one could multiply, one could avoid a multiplication step.  Though some processors include fast count-leading-zeroes instructions, I don't know any way to exploit them via Java.  On some platforms, casting both arguments to `float` or `double` and multiplying them might be the fastest approach; if the result is much less than 2^63, the integer result cannot overflow, and if it's much greater, it's certain to.  When it's close to 2^63, the integer result will either be correct or negative.

Comment: The "correct" way to compute the number of leading zeros in Java is `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(long)`, which uses the baseline Hacker's Delight implementation. The only way to take advantage of a processor-specific optimization would be through JNI, which imposes more overhead than it would probably be worth, even after inlining by the JIT compiler during JVM optimization. I like the cast-and-verify solution, though. I'm guessing the single multiple would probably only take about 10 clock cycles, and it has an easy-to-understand implementation.

Comment: @NathanRyan: If you do the cast-to-float method, a product above 9.223373E+18 should be considered an overflow; one below 9.223371E+18 should be considered safe.  Only a few values in the middle really need to be tested.

Comment: Thanks for the specifics.